# Equivalent of e.ReturnValue in EntityDataSource

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource, entitydatasource

I'm using EntityDataSource with DetailsView in my ASP.NET application. I want to get identity column value after inserting the record. ObjectDataSource has e.ReturnValue property I want to know its equivalent in EntityDataSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the `Inserted` event, which is an `EventHandler<EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs>`.

The `EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs` instance has an Entity property, representing the newly inserted entity.

```
void EntityDataSource1_Inserted(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangedEventArgs e) {
    YourEntityType newlyAdded = (YourEntityType)e.Entity;
    int newId = newlyAdded.Id;
}
```

Comment: Thank for the reply. Can you please have a look at my another question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603383/use-stored-procedure-in-entitydatasource